# Feature engineering - house price prediction (small dataset)

Tags: regression, feature-engineering, prediction

I am working on the task of predicting real estate prices. My dataset has only 10 variables described below. I'm thinking about feature engineering but nothing comes to mind.

Variables:

`street`

`city`

`zip code`

`rooms`

`bathrooms`

`square feet`

`type`

`price`

`latitude`

`longitude`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

latitude, longitude could be used for clustering. Then you should set cluster_id to every house as a new feature.

Also it possible to use geo coordinates to calculate the distances to important points (to the city center for example)